# Could it make sense to calculate the "distance correlation" among two probability measures (probability distributions)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

**Introduction.** The ["distance correlation" introduced by Székely et al.(2007)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25464608), [is a measure of dependence between two paired random vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_correlation), i.e. $X$ in $\mathbb{R}^{p}$ and $Y$ in $\mathbb{R}^{q}$, and it is usually indicated as $\mathcal{R}(X,Y)$.

**Question.** If I have two probability measures $P$ and $Q$ on a measurable space $\left( \mathcal{\Omega},\mathcal{A}\right)$, where $\mathcal{\Omega}$ is a set, called sample space, and $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma-$algebra on $\mathcal{\Omega}$, would it make sense to calculate the distance correlation among the two probability measures $P$ and $Q$, i.e. $\mathcal{R}(P,Q)$? Or is it a nonsense?